# Python tkinter button showing script to scrolledtext box

Tags: python, tkinter, button

**When i press the start button, it runs the other script but only shows it in the other terminal, not in the GUI scrolledtext box i have. is there a simple fix for my problem? not finding an answer anywhere.**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys
import os
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

root = Tk()
root.title("WLP")
root.geometry("950x450")
root.iconbitmap("Vo1d.ico")
root.configure(bg='#0c0c0c')

def clickstart():
  os.system('python WLP.py')

Button1 = Button(root, text="START", bg="#0c0c0c", fg="#C0C0C0", command=clickstart)  #)
Textbox = tkst.ScrolledText(root, width=75, height=10, bg="#0c0c0c", fg="#C0C0C0")
Button1.grid(row=10, column=5, pady=15)
Textbox.grid(row=17, column=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: im trying to get the results of 'wlp.py' to show in my scrolledtext (textbox) when i press button1. all im getting at the moment is the results of 'wlp.py' showing in the terminal behind my GUI when i press button1. @PCM

Comment: `os.system()` does not give you any access to the output of the command being run.  You need something from the `subprocess` module instead - `.run()`, perhaps.

Comment: @DwughtFromTheOffice , This worked with a little correction when running the .py file. however after compiling the script and pressing the button in the .exe file, it does not show the results in the scrolledtext (textbox) at all. any ideas or fixes you or anyone can think of? in the terminal behind the .exe file it states:  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python', 'wlp1.py']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

Comment: @Vo1d It is because `check=True` is used in `subprocess.run(...)` in the answer.  Exception will be raised if the return code of `WPL.py` is not zero.  Remove `check=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far from a good way to do it, but this should work (after importing subprocess)

```
def clickstart():
    output = subprocess.run(['python', 'WPL.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)
    output = str(output.stdout, encoding='utf-8')
    Textbox.insert(1.0, output)
```

Comment: The index to `insert` should be  a string, not a floating point number. The floating point number will work in this specific case but the function is defined to take a string.